# AngularJS - Find object in ng-repeat after updating a field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I am working on an online dashboard. This dashboard has a page which consists of all the tasks related to a certain project. Each task has fields such as the amount of hours that were booked to the task, and the progress (0 until 100%).

[image: The table looks as follows]

It is possible to change the progress field as it consists of a dropdown menu with all the possible percentages. I used to change the progress, select each row that I altered and clicked on an 'update tasks' button in order to send them to my Controller and update them. This was fine until a colleague of mine came up with the idea of automatically updating the task once the value of the progress field was changed. I can place an `ng-click` on each value which activates as soon as I change the value.

My question however, how can I let my controller know what row I am working in at that moment. Let's say I have 3 different tasks and change the progress of task 2. My controller should know it has to send the ID of task 2 to the server to update its content.

As soon as the value of task 2 changes to, for example 30%, the updateTaskById() method executes. This method should update the task in the database with the new value. How do I let my controller know what task it has to update.

HTML

```
    <td md-cell class="tdWidth">
                <md-select ng-model="task.custom_fields['96203']" placeholder="100%">
                    <md-option value="0" ng-click="updateTaskById()">0%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.1" ng-click="updateTaskById()">10%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.2" ng-click="updateTaskById()">20%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.3" ng-click="updateTaskById()">30%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.4" ng-click="updateTaskById()">40%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.5" ng-click="updateTaskById()">50%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.6" ng-click="updateTaskById()">60%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.7" ng-click="updateTaskById()">70%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.8" ng-click="updateTaskById()">80%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="0.9" ng-click="updateTaskById()">90%</md-option>
                    <md-option value="1" ng-click="updateTaskById()">100%</md-option>
                </md-select>
            </td>
```

Angular Controller:

```
    $scope.updateTaskById = function() {
        // Update functionality here
    };
```

Thanks in advance, I hope my question is clear enough.

EDIT: As seen in Alexandru's answer, it is possible to send values of the task I was altering from my `ng-click`. For example: `updateTaskById(task.task_id)`.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you are trying to achieve without code

Comment: @Mistalis I have updated the question to try and make it more clear for possible future references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value to `ng-click` method. For instance,

```
 <md-option value="0" ng-click="updateTaskById(0)">0%</md-option>
```

JS

```
$scope.updateTaskById(value){
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionat Mihai Thank you again, your previous answer was the right one. I was trying to tell my controller which task it had to update. I did not know it was possible to send the task.task_id inside my ng-click.

Comment: Ok..don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: Accepted your answer, I had to wait for the required wait time to be over. Thanks again!